# Spoof MAC without limitation in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, mac-address, kali-linux, spoofing

I am able to change my MAC to anything in Kali Linux, but not in Windows? It needs to be changed to 50:b7:c3:3d:1c:b6. I tried using SMAC and no luck. I heard there were limits on what I can change it to, but how to go around them?

Comment: In the device manager open the properties for the network card. On the advanced tab there should be a Network Adddress property that you can set.

Comment: @Brian don't you think that that would be the first thing I would try? The change doesn't work as its limited to the numbers you could use.